# Something is wrong with this simple query. Can anybody see it?

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert

OK, this simple little query is kicking my butt. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$format = "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'";
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `Presentations` (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)  VALUES (". $format,$sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc ."')");
```

I realize there is an extra single quote near the end there, but I echoed $insertSQL and it gets cut off if I don't add it.  Here's what the echo looks like, with the error message that accompanies it:

```
INSERT INTO `Presentations` (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)
    VALUES ('VT6Smic28','http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fdocs%2Fadoc.html','greg.mcgee%40advetel.com','gregmcgee%40yahoo.com','Tue%2C+21+Feb+2012+09%3A57%3A51+CST')

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1
```

Without the additional single quote, I get a similar error message, except that it says it is  near " at line 1.

Comment: The only thing wrong with it is the single quote on the end I guess.

Comment: You are concatenating string values into an SQL query, that's what's wrong.

Comment: *"it gets cut off if I don't add it"*  What?  Show us exactly what you mean here.  Also, that string formatting is a bit slipshod.  You say: `sprintf("START".$fmt, $a, $b, $c, $d, $e . "END")`, which is appending the "END" text to the final argument and then format-interpolating.  Your `$format` should probably be the whole INSERT statement.  Better, use prepared statements and don't `sprintf` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing `'` right before the final close parentheses (`"')"`). Doesn't matter what you echoed; why should that be there if `$format` is what you're really putting into the query?

Answer: `$format` isn't what you're inserting into the SQL. You meant to use `sprintf` on it first, but haven't.

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean I "meant" to use sprintf but haven't?

Comment: @I_miss_Steve_already You meant to call `sprintf` on `$format` alone. Instead, you called it on `$format` mixed in with a larger string, and mixed up your syntax while so doing (by appending to `$lastacc` instead of the format string).

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
$format = "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'";
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `Presentations` (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)  VALUES (". $format .")",$sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc);
```

Comment: Aha! Got it.  I have the sprintf in the wrong place, so its picking up "INSERT INTO..." as the format string, which screws it up. Here's the way it works:
$format = "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'";
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO `Presentations` (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)  VALUES (". sprintf($format,$sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc).")";

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert 6 values into a table with 5 columns specified. Using the method you do for `sprintf`, the `format` variable should not even need to be used. The other variables you state should be sent as parameters for the `sprintf`.

Try using

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `Presentations` (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", $sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc );
```

Comment: This might work, but the way I did it above works, and it makes sense to me. So I'm going with it.  Thanks for your comments.  They were all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$insertSQL = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO `Presentations` (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)  VALUES (" .$format, $sn, $doc, $trackr, $recip, $lastacc);
$insertSQL = $insertSQL . ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

That `'` is the issue I think. Otherwise it works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1f3a/1

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
$format = "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'";
$insertSQL = sprintf("
    INSERT INTO `Presentations` 
      (serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed)  
    VALUES (". $format.")"  
                    ,$sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc 
                    );
```